# Is pstool incompatible with hyperref?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pstool

I wanted to create a figure with clickable references do different chapters of my document. Therefore, I wanted to use pstool to replace placehoders in the figure with appropriate references.

If I not use hyperref, the placeholders are replaced correctly.

However as soon as I use hyperref, the processing of figures fails.
I get "An error occured processing graphic: ‘./trial.eps’ Check the log file for compilation errors: ‘./trial-pstool.log’" message.

The log contains no errors, but warnings about undefined references.

To recreate the problem you should download the [trial.eps from pstool example](https://github.com/wspr/pstool/raw/master/example/trial.eps).
As soon as you add the hyperref package in the example.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <= uncommenting this line breaks processing
\begin{document}
\psfragfig*{trial}{
  \psfrag{[Mp]}{See section ~\ref{sec:test}}
}

Some random text before the section.
\pagebreak
\section{Test section}
\label{sec:test}
Here is some random text.
\end{document}
```

the document stops to compile correctly with:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape example.tex
```

The pdf is produced, but you'll see the error box instead of the figure.

You can still compile it with:

```
latex --shell-escape example.tex
latex --shell-escape example.tex
dvipdf example.dvi
```

and you'll get clickable reference in the figure.

Unfortunately, for certain reasons I'm forced to use pdflatex instead of latex/dvipdf.

Comment: At the moment your document does not compilable at all, since nobody has `macros.tex` at hand. Please post a compilable version of your document, not just fragments

Comment: It is only a part of the document. It shows how to modify the document that is available at https://github.com/wspr/pstool/tree/master/example (link provided in the question).

Comment: Well, I am not inclined to follow links whereas you could reduce your document in order to present it here, which is the default way.

Comment: The whole example is rather big, as it contains the document and the figures. I think in that case it's easier to get it from the github. Of course I may be wrong.

Comment: At the moment I have a suboptimal workaround. I compile with latex. To avoid non-breakable references except of hyperref I use "\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}". Finally I convert dvi do pdf with dvipdf.

Comment: @wzab please do not use external links, the question and answers are archived here forever and will not make sense if the code in that github link changes. please make a small but complete example. note links in included pdf do not work when pdf are included by pdftex

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem but for me it works correctly, I have downloaded some files from your github link, added `hyperref`, and compiled with `pdflatex`. I don't get errors and the `pstool` replacements in the figures are processed. It could be a version problem, I use `pdflatex` 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017), pstool v1.5e (2018/01/20) and hyperref v6.86b (2018/02/06). Which versions do you use?

Comment: Also, as others have commented, it would be much easier to answer (and to isolate the problem) if you can minimize the example and post it here. The error is with `trial.eps`, so keep only those five lines in the document (around line 40) and remove everything else. Try to limit as much as you can the use of secondary files (like `macros.tex` and `trial.tex`), you may get some warnings but that should not affect the issue. In general, make it as easy as you can to reproduce the problem, without downloads and lots of files (except downloading `trial.eps` of course, since that is essential).

Comment: Would it make sense to disable the loading of hyperref entirely in graphics being processed by pstool? As David said, I don’t believe any of the hyperlinks can survive being embedded separately.

Comment: OK. Thanks for comments. I have modified the question so that it contains the whole LaTeX example code.