# Proper toolchain for pdfLaTeX and psfrag including hyperref

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, preview, psfrag, pstool

I am writing a comprehensive scientific thesis. In December 2020, my toolchain stopped working, which combined pdfLaTeX, pstool to apply psfrag, and hyperref.

I reported the issue here [pdfLaTeX fails on pstool when hyperref is included](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570404/pdflatex-fails-on-pstool-when-hyperref-is-included). Maybe it is related to here [Is pstool incompatible with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470598/is-pstool-incompatible-with-hyperref)?

It turned out that this is a bug that cannot be easily solved, and I was informed that it is related to the packages `pstool` and `preview`, but not directly `hyperref` (see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/166). @ulrike-fischer proposed a workaround that really saved me in that moment - thanks again for the quick help for a newbie! The error, however, had been reported by her in advance (see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2020-11/msg00000.html).

Upon her advice, I created bug reports for `pstool` and `preview`:

- I placed a bug report in the GitHub repository of `pstool` here https://github.com/wspr/pstool/issues/33. Unfortunately, there is no reaction and I am not sure whether the maintainer is willing to update the package. The last update has been in 2018, and I was not able to reach the maintainer by eMail to get a life sign.
- I reported on the mailing list for `preview` bug reports, see history here https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-auctex@gnu.org/msg03845.html. I was informed that changes within the package `hyperref` are to blaim and that a bug fix is not likely to happen under these conditions, considering the effort. Furthermore, I was pointed to using a legacy LaTeX version which is indeed a solution for now, but not the future.

**Please, let me know which toolchains you would use in that situation, using MikTeX under Windows 10** . Considering the responses above, I am not sure that my original toolchain will be fixed, and clearly, I am not in a position to push any voluntary maintainer! So I might use the workaround for some time, but I would welcome an approach that is likely working in the future as well.

Note, according to the `pstool` workflow, I included all `psfrag` commands in separate *.tex files named identical to their corresponding *.eps figures, which I would prefer to keep.

So far, I tried:

- Changing the build chain to `TeX -> DviPs -> PS -> PDF`, but this does not allow me to use PNGs anymore. Encapsulating in EPS blowed up file size and is always extra work. Furthermore, hyperlinks in BibTeX have issues with line breaks.
- Switching to `epstopdf`, but this did not allow me to include `psfrag` easily
- Moving to `auto-pst-pdf`. It is sad but funny that this package is maintained by the maintainer of `pstool` who advises not to use it anymore and to switch to `pstool` if possible. Contrarily, he updated `auto-pst-pdf` in 2020, thus it is more recent than `pstool`.

The last option is my fallback at the moment, and even processes my *.tex files containing `psfrag` commands per image. It is missing the elegance of `pstool` for individual image processing and thus takes lots of extra compilation time. Plus, I am afraid that the package maintainer will consider this as a legacy package soon as announced.

I am looking forward to any advice or comment. In case you have a similar issue, this thread is also meant to provide an overview on my approaches so far... maybe it helps.

Thank you!

Comment: the claim on the auctex list that hyperref is to blame is wrong. The problem is in preview.sty. I sent the maintainer an example without hyperref as a proof some weeks ago.

Comment: beside this using pdfcrop instead of preview  with `\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}` works for me.

Comment: ... that... is really awesome. It works for me as well. Thank you! - Is there any limitation of ```pdfcrop``` compared to ```preview``` in this approach, or should I generally be fine with this in the future as well?

Comment: Just as a side note: This also affects package `pst-pdf` (https://github.com/rolfn/pst-pdf/issues/6) as well as `pstricks-pdf` which uses the former one

Comment: The problem is that we cannot expect a fix for ```preview```, except some new maintainer gets involved - or we collect enough money to pay the current ones. But I don't know the sum we would need to collect.