# pstool using pdfcrop fails on complex document

Tags: pdftex, pdfcrop, pstool

Following a proposal here [Proper toolchain for pdfLaTeX and psfrag including hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587774/proper-toolchain-for-pdflatex-and-psfrag-including-hyperref), I switched my `pstool` crop stage to `pdfcrop` to avoid a bug in `preview`. I compile a complex thesis document, distributed over several *.tex files.

Now the pdfLaTeX run fails on converting the *.eps files to *.pdf files whenever I cause a new conversion of an *.eps image without(!) cleaning the project in advance, deleting all temporary files. Specifically, the error

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1772 ...always_the_chapter_with_the_changed_image.aux}
                                                
?
```

occurs in the *.tex file that contains the image to be converted. This can be reproduced for all images in all chapters.

I found one possible hint: The file ...always_the_chapter_with_the_changed_image.aux has a structure like

```
\relax
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {6}Implementierung einer digitalen Werkzeugkette}{177}{chapter.6}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{lof}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
...
...
\newlabel{fig:Nizam_Total@cref}{{[figure][3][6]6.3}{[1][182][]183}}
\@writefile
```

ending with the `\@writefile` line, while all other chapters continue in their *.aux files with a list like

```
\setcounter{page}{79}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{enumi}{4}
\setcounter{enumii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{0}
\setcounter{part}{0}
```

which is missing for the chapter containing the changed *.eps image.

In order to prepare a minimum example, I tried to find a minimum project complexity to reproduce the error, but it is not easy. Sometimes, simply removing normal text led to a normal compilation. But also a plain large document of repeated text compiles well. So I assume it is somehow related to document complexity.

Note, when I clean all temporary files in advance, the document compiles well!

Can you advise me how to track the issue? As I told, my techniques failed to provide a proper minimum example...

Comment: your aux file is corrupted, simply delete it. That usually happens because you killed the job (eg killing the window from the operating system) after an error rather than using `x` to let tex finish cleanly and close open files.

Comment: Yes, deleting all aux files leads to a subsequent proper run until I change the image again. But changing the images and thus calling a pstoll conversion leads(!) to the error that kills the job. So the root cause is within this run. Always manually deleting the aux files leads to very slow compilations. I would be really happy to find the error rather than deleting the files in advance...

Comment: it is impossible to tell what is killing the tex process with the information provided. The error message is really unrelated to to actual issue, just tex process is killed by the operating system and files it is writing (eg aux) get truncated, so on the next run you get essentially random error from the incomplete file. So the error you get reading the aux back tells you nothing about the error that corrupted the file originally.

Comment: Uff... So I will have to continue in trying to find a minimum example...?

Comment: if removing simple test help it could be due to changes in the page breaks.